# Why quizfile.write(" ") is not working from the Second for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this question Automate the boring Stuff book. The Code is also given there but When I was Practising this on my own the problem I am getting is this code is not writing in the files after the first for loop.

```
import random
import os
capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
   'Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver',
   'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee',
   'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois':
   'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas':
   'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine':
   'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan':
   'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri':
   'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada':
   'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton', 
   'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh',
   'North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
   'Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence',
   'South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee':
   'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont':
   'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia', 
   'West Virginia': 'Charleston', 'Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}
#print (capitals)
for q in range(35):
    quizfile = open("capitalquiz%s.txt" %(q + 1), 'w')
    answerfile = open("Answerfile%s.txt"%(q + 1),'w')
    quizfile.write('Name:\n\nDate:\n\nPeriod:\n\n')
    quizfile.write((' ' * 20) + 'State Capitals Quiz (Form %s)' % (q + 1))
    quizfile.write('\n\n')

    states = list(capitals.keys())
    random.shuffle(states)
    quizfile.write("wefkjqennqkeanfeqkjn")
for i in range(50):
    correct_answer = capitals[states[i]]
    wrong_answer = list(capitals.values())
    del wrong_answer[correct_answer.index(correct_answer)]
    wrong_answers = random.sample(wrong_answer,3)
    answer_option = wrong_answers + [correct_answer]
    random.shuffle(answer_option)




for item in range(50):  
    #quizfile.write("******************************************************")
    quizfile.write("%s.what is the capital of %s" %(item+1,states[item]))
    for i in range(4):
        quizfile.write("%s. %s\n" %('ABCD'[i],answer_option[i]))
        answerfile.write("%s. %s\n" %(q+1,'ABCD'[answer_option.index(correct_answer)]))


quizfile.close()
answerfile.close()
```

Comment: Are you not getting any errors? I can see that you open `quizfile` inside of a for loop 35 times. Edit: Ah, I think your formatting may have not carried over correctly.

Comment: No I am Not getting any errors.This program will create 35 text files. Every file will have 1 question and a different file will have it's answer. The first for loop is working but the second for loop can not able to write anything inside files

Comment: That is because you're attempting to access a bunch of undeclared variables, you're indentation is off and you have an extra for-loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help @cssko. I found out the problem.But I guess that's not what you described. The all questions and answers are being written on the last file only,not in their respective files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some for loops that need to be nested within others. You're attempting to access out of scope variables as it is now.

Your code, cleaned up:

```
import random
import os
capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
   'Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver',
   'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee',
   'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois':
   'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas':
   'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine':
   'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan':
   'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri':
   'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada':
   'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton',
   'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh',
   'North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
   'Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence',
   'South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee':
   'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont':
   'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia',
   'West Virginia': 'Charleston', 'Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}

for q in range(35):
    quizfile = open("capitalquiz%s.txt" %(q + 1), 'w')
    answerfile = open("Answerfile%s.txt"%(q + 1),'w')
    quizfile.write('Name:\n\nDate:\n\nPeriod:\n\n')
    quizfile.write((' ' * 20) + 'State Capitals Quiz (Form %s)' % (q + 1))
    quizfile.write('\n\n')

    states = list(capitals.keys())
    random.shuffle(states)
    for i in range(50):
        correct_answer = capitals[states[i]]
        wrong_answer = list(capitals.values())
        del wrong_answer[correct_answer.index(correct_answer)]
        wrong_answers = random.sample(wrong_answer,3)
        answer_option = wrong_answers + [correct_answer]
        random.shuffle(answer_option)
        quizfile.write("%s.what is the capital of %s \n" %(i+1,states[i]))
        for j in range(4):
            quizfile.write("%s. %s\n" %('ABCD'[j],answer_option[j]))
            quizfile.write('\n')
        answerfile.write("%s. %s\n" %(i+1,'ABCD'[answer_option.index(correct_answer)]))

    quizfile.close()
    answerfile.close()
```

It's not the prettiest but I think it does what you're trying to do.